# Cannot authenticate Azure Bot with AAD (bot sdk 4)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-bot-service

I tried the tutorial on the [official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cbot-oauth) and followed all the steps. If I test the azure bot service from azure portal, it asks for signin and gives me access token. But when I'm trying from Bot emulator, the request url for login seems odd

---

[image]

If I click confirm, it's signing me in directly without redirecting to azure login page and shows me the following

---

[image]

This does not look like an access token. Am I missing something here?

Btw, I just changed the appsettings.json file from the tutorial with my app id and secrets. Nothing else is changed. I've also made the service principle and granted permission. So there should not be any problem. I am just getting started with azure bot service. So any advice will be appreciated :)

Comment: It is odd , that is a conversation ID instead of an access token . Could you pls have a check your "OAuth Connection Settings" in setting of your bot ? You can click "Test Connection" to test if you can get the access token.

Comment: yes, i am getting actual access token when testing the connection from azure portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you pls have a check that if you configed **[ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)** for your bot emulator ?

I got the same issue on my side if I remove ngrok setting in my bot emulator.Maybe it caused some networks issues while bot emulator communicating with Azure platform.

You can download it from previous link and config it on your bot emulator here : 
[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: does it mention in any official document?

Comment: Welcome !  Maybe this doc will be helpful :https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/wiki/Tunneling-(ngrok)